# Conditioning on elements of matrix in JIT-ted function

Tags: python, jax

I have a function that looks like this

```
        @jax.jit
        def f(R):
            tr = jnp.trace(R)

            r00 = R[0, 0]
            r01 = R[0, 1]
            r02 = R[0, 2]
            r10 = R[1, 0]
            r11 = R[1, 1]
            r12 = R[1, 2]
            r20 = R[2, 0]
            r21 = R[2, 1]
            r22 = R[2, 2]

            condw = tr > 0
            condx = (r00 > r11) and (r00 > r22)
            condy = (r11 > r22)
            # ... do some more things based on the conditions
```

where `R` is a 3x3 `DeviceArray`. When I try JIT-ing this function as shown above, I get the following error:

```
File "/path/to/my/file", line 90, in f
    condx = (r00 > r11) and (r00 > r22)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/core.py", line 544, in __bool__
    def __bool__(self): return self.aval._bool(self)
  File "/Users/me/miniconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/jax/core.py", line 989, in error
    raise ConcretizationTypeError(arg, fname_context)
jax._src.traceback_util.UnfilteredStackTrace: jax._src.errors.ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: Traced<ShapedArray(bool[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=0/1)>
The problem arose with the `bool` function. 
While tracing the function f at /path/to/my/file:75 for jit, this concrete value was not available in Python because it depends on the value of the argument 'R'.
```

I'm not really sure what's wrong with computing this boolean value that prevents this function from being JIT-ted.

```
        condx = (r00 > r11) and (r00 > r22)
```

Any hints would be much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From [#3761](https://github.com/google/jax/issues/3761), use bitwise operators instead of logical operators.

This works.

```
condx = (r00 > r11) & (r00 > r22)
```